# Child entitied removed via native SQL still exist in entityManager

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a code like this in Java (hibernate 3.1):

```
EntityManager manager = ...;
Entity parent = manager.find(...);
removeChildrenSQL(parent, manager); // here DELETE FROM ... is executed
manager.flush();
```

I need the removed entities not to be seen from hibernate anymore.

I tried (and these didn't work):

1) manager.refresh(parent);

2) manually refresh the removed entities

3) reloading parent with all children.

How can I do it?

Comment: post removeChildrenSQL please!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
manager.detach(parent);
parent = manager.find(Entity.class, parent.getId());
```

(You might also need to detach the children, especially if you modified them before removing them)

Comment: javax.persistence.EntityManager doesn't have the detach() method, so what method do you refer to?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 0):

Call `session.evict(childEntity)` for all children, where session is your hibernate session.

To get the hibernate session use:

```
org.hibernate.Session session = (org.hibernate.Session)manager.getDelegate();
```

Or if you're in a session bean you can get it injected using `@PersistenceContext` annotation.

Update: Maybe your problem is related to hibernate's cache. Try setting

```
<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
```

in your `prersistence.xml`.
After that a manager.refresh(parent) should do the trick.

Update2:
Or maybe the children are in a LAZY collection, in which case you have two solutions:
Annotate the children with:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
```

in which case you still need to do manager.refresh(parent);
or use:

```
 Hibernate.initialize(parent.getChidren());
```

Comment: @Oleg how do you remove the entities? Have you tried removing them from the list, too? Post more code if you still need help.

Comment: You mean exec DELETE and then manually set NULL references? No. But Isn't there a common way of reloading entity changed by native SQL?

Comment: @Oleg I made some changes in the answer, maybe it will help. I have to go to sleep, so good luck with your problem!